# InfluxDB: Is flux the only way to add simple calculations as a column in a query?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I'm trying a query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT("value"), F("value"),G("value") FROM "someTable" WHERE time >= t1 AND time < t2 GROUP BY (aggregateWindow),*
```

F = sum of squares, and this wouldn't be too hard if I could do something like the following `SUM("value"*"value")`, but apparently that doesn't work in Influx (or maybe I'm using the syntax wrong).

G = time stamp of aggregate in unix epoch + aggregateWindow. So for example, if aggregateWindow == 1s, then I would want the following output (assuming there's only one point in that aggregateWindow whose value is `value`):

```
time                value F  G
----                ----- -- -----------------
1600272300000000000 1     1  1600272301000000000
1600272301000000000 2     4  1600272302000000000
1600272302000000000 3     9  1600272303000000000
1600272303000000000 4     16 1600272304000000000
1600272304000000000 5     25 1600272305000000000
```

I know you can implement sum of squares via flux as [described here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5364), but I'm worried about the performance of Flux vs regular Influx queries as [mentioned here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/18088). So basically I'm asking, is flux the only and most efficient way of making a query like this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT("value"), 
 "value"*"value" AS F,
 POW("value", 2) AS FwithPOWfunction
FROM "someTable" 
WHERE 
  time >= t1 AND time < t2 
GROUP BY (aggregateWindow)
```

You can't create new time column, but you can apply offset to time grouping `GROUP BY time(time_interval,[<offset_interval])`

Doc is your good friend to get more details and learn correct syntax:

- https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill
- https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#pow